# Не ставятся модули через pip

Tags: python, python-3.x

При попытке установить любой пакет через pip (например pip install youtube_dl) просто пишет в консоли слово Python и не ставит пакет. Что делать в такой ситуации?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть вероятность, что у Вас не стоит пайтон, или консоль не знает какой использовать. Копайте в эту сторону.

Comment: Команда `where python` что выводит?

Comment: команда where python ничего не выдаёт, сам python установлен

Comment: "команда where python ничего не выдаёт" - значит неправильно установлен. Если бы был правильно установлен, то выдавало бы путь до python.exe

Comment: Попробуй python -m pip install

Answer (score 0):

советую попробовать работать в pyCharm и от туда через внутреннюю консоль ставить модули
на виртуалку это намного удобнее